# How to simplify Import

Tags: python, python-import

How to simplify this to be more small

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import random, os
```

Thanks

Comment: Drop the `from` imports and use, for example `random.randint`, and `tk.ttk`.

Comment: What's wrong with these very few lines of imports? Also, note that [the PEP8 part about imports](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) recommends `import random` and `import os` on separate lines rather than `import random, os`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only import them,

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import os
```

then use in code like this,

```
random.randint

tk.ttk
```

**Updated**

But according to best practice use this

```
import os
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randint
```

Comment: The normal, traditional way to import Tkinter is the one provided in the OP's code: `from tkinter import *; from tkinter import ttk`, not the one you suggest here. Note also that PEP8 recommends putting imports on separate lines rather that things like `import random, os`.

Comment: I would argue it's not a best practice to import tkinter with `from tkinter import *`. It's how some tutorials do it but it goes against PEP8.

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep only one for `random`, one for `tkinter`
2. for each choose :

   - `from PACKAGE import STUFF1, STUFF2` : there is not so much imports, and name are easily understandable
   - `import PACKAGE as p` : there is many imports to do from, or import name can be confusing
3. **NEVER USE** `*`, always explicit names
4. Follow community "rules", for mainstream packages

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   ```

Comment: It's a invalid syntax when i do "from tkinter import *, ttk"

Comment: @Aragor i never mentionned `*`, STUFF is an explicit name

Answer (score 0):

constructing on @SAM's answer, you can further reduce a line of code like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random, os
```

If you want to further make it a 1-liner, then you must perform blasphemy in python: the semicolon

```py
import tkinter as tk; import random, os
```

Comment: Please don't. This goes against PEP8 ("Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged") and the traditional way of importing Tkinter which is widely respected in code using it.